# Sum values using lookup for comma-separated list in one of the columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table which has some string keys and numerical values like this-

```
-----------------
| Keys | Scores |
-----------------
|  k1  |   10   |
|  k2  |   15   |
|  k3  |    8   |
-----------------
```

Now there's another table which has comma separated keys like this-

```
--------------------
| Keys     | Total |
--------------------
| k1,k2    |       |
|  k3      |       |
| k1,k2,k3 |       |
--------------------
```

I want to fill the "Total" column by referencing the table. Is it possible  in excel with formulas or VBScript?

Comment: Both are very possible. You can use substitute or find as a formula to determine if/how often a value appears in a string. Multiply that by your lookup column. While that works fine with just 3 different keys, to be more dynamic and account for more keys I think working through VBA and create a UDF would be best. Put your second tables keys into an array using split function and loop through the array.

Comment: @JvdV Can you help me with that? I have no experience with excel formulas or VBScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula iterates the parts and uses SUMIFS to return the number to SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(E2,",",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(E2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E2,",",""))+1))-1)*999+1,999))))
```

No vba or named range workarounds needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach which uses the Evaluate method to create an array that consists of the criteria that will be passed to SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(...)).

[image]

1) First, select cell F2.

2) Then, define the following name (Ribbon >> Formulas >> Defined Names >> Define Name)...

```
Name:  MyArray

Refers to:  =EVALUATE("{"""&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE('Sheet1'!$E2," ",""),",",""",""")&"""}")

Click OK
```

Change the sheet name accordingly.

3) Then, enter the following formula in F2, and copy down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF($A$2:$A$4,MyArray,$B$2:$B$4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, y As Long, w As Long
    Dim arrLookingValues As Variant, arrDataStored As Variant, arrValues As Variant
    Dim Total As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Set an array which store Keys & Scores
        arrDataStored = .Range("A2:B4")

        'Set an array which store what we are looking for
        arrLookingValues = .Range("D2:D4")

        For i = LBound(arrLookingValues) To UBound(arrLookingValues)

            Total = 0

            'Set an array with the values of each row we are looking for
            arrValues = Split(arrLookingValues(i, 1), ",")

            'Loop the array which store the values we are looking for
            For y = LBound(arrValues) To UBound(arrValues)

                'Loop the array which store both Keys & Scores
                For w = LBound(arrDataStored) To UBound(arrDataStored)
                    'If we find a match
                    If Trim(arrValues(y)) = arrDataStored(w, 1) Then
                        'Add Total
                        Total = Total + arrDataStored(w, 2)
                        Exit For
                    End If

                Next w

            Next y

            'Print the result in column E
            .Range("E" & i + 1).Value = Total

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]